# replace subset of vector values with subset average

Tags: r, regex, subset, average

I have a somewhat messy data frame where subjects are ranked, but some are tied for rankings.

```
    subj<-c("A","B","C,D,E","C,D,E","C,D,E","F","G,H","G,H","I")
    rank<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    df<-data.frame(rank,subj)
    df
       rank  subj
    1    1     A
    2    2     B
    3    3 C,D,E
    4    4 C,D,E
    5    5 C,D,E
    6    6     F
    7    7   G,H
    8    8   G,H
    9    9     I
```

Where individuals are tied, I need to express their ranks as averages of the tied positions. Something like

```
    n.rank n.subj
1    1.0      A
2    2.0      B
3    4.0      C
4    4.0      D
5    4.0      E
6    6.0      F
7    7.5      G
8    7.5      H
9    9.0      I
```

I have tried using `strngsplit()`and naming elements of the list by the ranks, but I end up with a data frame that seems equally difficult to deal with.

```
 a<-strsplit(as.character(df$subj),",")
 names(a)<-df$rank
 b<-melt(a)
 colnames(b)<-c("n.subj","n.rank")
 b[1:10,]
     n.subj n.rank
 1       A      1
 2       B      2
 3       C      3
 4       D      3
 5       E      3
 6       C      4
 7       D      4
 8       E      4
 9       C      5
 10      D      5
```

I also reach a dead end when I use `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()` to try to identify ranks that need to be averaged.

```
    m<-gregexpr(",+",df$subj)
    df$no.avg<-melt(lapply(regmatches(df$subj, m),length))[,1]+1
    df
     rank  subj no.avg
  1    1     A      1
  2    2     B      1
  3    3 C,D,E      3
  4    4 C,D,E      3
  5    5 C,D,E      3
  6    6     F      1
  7    7   G,H      2
  8    8   G,H      2
  9    9     I      1
```

Any creative solutions out there? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my attempt. I first calculate the average rank, then split the subjects of the same rank into rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
subj <- c("A", "B", "C,D,E", "C,D,E", "C,D,E", "F", "G,H", "G,H", "I")
rank <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
df <- data.frame(rank, subj)

df %>% 
  group_by(subj) %>% 
  summarise(rank = mean(rank)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(tibble(subj = unlist(strsplit(.$subj, ",")), rank = .$rank)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
   subj  rank
* <chr> <dbl>
1     A   1.0
2     B   2.0
3     C   4.0
4     D   4.0
5     E   4.0
6     F   6.0
7     G   7.5
8     H   7.5
9     I   9.0
```

---

Another approach:

```
m <- aggregate(rank~subj, data=df, mean)
m <- apply(m, 1, function(x) data.frame(subj = unlist(strsplit(x[1], ",")), rank = x[2]))
m <- do.call(rbind, m)
rownames(m) <- NULL
m
```

Output:

```
subj rank
1    A  1.0
2    B  2.0
3    C  4.0
4    D  4.0
5    E  4.0
6    F  6.0
7    G  7.5
8    H  7.5
9    I  9.0
```

Comment: In the end, I didn't use this script because I don't live in the `tidyverse`, but your logic of averaging the rank by subject first made the solution clear. Many thanks.

Comment: @gavago You are welcome. I have added the another approach that doesn't require `tidyverse` or `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` version:

```
#library(data.table) #version 1.9.8
setDT(df)
df[, .(subj=unlist(strsplit(subj[1], ",")), rank=mean(rank)), by=subj][,-1]

#   subj rank
#1:    A  1.0
#2:    B  2.0
#3:    C  4.0
#4:    D  4.0
#5:    E  4.0
#6:    F  6.0
#7:    G  7.5
#8:    H  7.5
#9:    I  9.0
```

Comment: When I run your `data.table` code on my example script, the output is simply `-1`. I'm not very familiar with `data.table`, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: @user3166232  Try removing the `[,-1]` from the end. You probably have a different version of the package causing some slight differences - i'm on v1.9.8.

Answer (score 2):

My version with `splitstackshape` and `aggregate`. The logic is same, we split the string by comma and take the mean by `subj`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
aggregate(rank~subj, cSplit(df, "subj", ",", "long"), mean)

#  subj rank
#1    A  1.0
#2    B  2.0
#3    C  4.0
#4    D  4.0
#5    E  4.0
#6    F  6.0
#7    G  7.5
#8    H  7.5
#9    I  9.0
```

where

```
cSplit(df, "subj", ",", "long")
```

gives

```
#     rank subj
# 1:    1    A
# 2:    2    B
# 3:    3    C
# 4:    3    D
# 5:    3    E
# 6:    4    C
# 7:    4    D
# 8:    4    E
# 9:    5    C
#10:    5    D
#11:    5    E
#12:    6    F
#13:    7    G
#14:    7    H
#15:    8    G
#16:    8    H
#17:    9    I
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `tidyverse`.  The dataset is converted to 'long' format by splitting the 'subj' column using `separate_rows`, then grouped by 'subj', get the `mean` of 'rank'

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df, subj) %>% 
         group_by(subj) %>%
         summarise(rank = mean(rank))
# A tibble: 9 × 2
#    subj  rank
#   <chr> <dbl>
#1     A   1.0
#2     B   2.0
#3     C   4.0
#4     D   4.0
#5     E   4.0
#6     F   6.0
#7     G   7.5
#8     H   7.5
#9     I   9.0
```